# Trailing newlines and the bash 'read' builtin

Tags: bash, shell, newline, built-in

In bash, this works:

```
echo -n $'a\nb\nc\n' | while read x; do echo = $x =; done
```

The while loops through three times

```
= a =
= b =
= c =
```

But imagine a text file that doesn't have the conventional trailing newline. I think that `read` should still work for all three lines, but it doesn't. I just get:

```
echo -n $'a\nb\nc' | while read x; do echo = $x =; done

= a =
= b =
```

The `help read` in bash doesn't really clarify.

**Note:** I don't need this resolved, and I can see some ways to fix it myself. I am curious, and I am tempted to file a bug report - I generally try myself to respect files that mightn't have the trailing new line. I came across this when using the -d option to read. `read -d " "` will split on spaces instead of newlines, but it will miss out on the last entry unless it has a trailing space.

(Ubuntu. GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release)

Comment: for what it's worth, your 2nd script works as the first with ksh. Good luck.

Comment: I just checked: `ksh`  behaves the same way as `bash` in this case, @shellter.

Comment: @codeforester  : I'm sure I tested this before posting, but no longer have access to the UWIN ksh93. Also it is possible that the version I was using is different that the version you are using, although I'm almost sure I saw this very issue come up in the UWIN/ksh email groups (~<10 yrs ago ;-) ). I like your alternate below. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ man bash
   read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]
          One line is read from the standard input, ...
```

I think the key is: `How to define "One line"`.
Does `text without a '\n' at the end` makes `One line`?
I guess `read` don't think so.

Comment: My text editor thinks it's a line, and I think every text editor will. So if the text editor can deal sensibly with files which don't have a newline as their very last character, then I think `read` should too :-)

Comment: `read` is correctly handling it - it reads every valid line.  It doesn't read incomplete lines as it has no idea whether they're "lines", an interrupted stream, a broken pipe, etc....

Spec: [a line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206);

Spec: [an incomplete line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_195);

`read` doesn't have the luxury of being able to assume that everything it operates on is a complete file intended for humans.

Standards aren't based on what (often buggy) text-editors think.

Answer (score 9):

If you want the above loop to process the incomplete line, do this:

```
echo -n $'a\nb\nc' | while read x || [[ $x ]]; do echo = $x =; done
```

which gives:

```
= a =
= b =
= c =
```

When `read` encounters the incomplete line, it does read that into the variable (`x` in this case) but returns a non-zero exit code which would end the loop, and `|| [[ $x ]]` takes care of running the loop for the incomplete line as well. When `read` is called the next time, there is nothing to read and it exits with 1, setting `x` to an empty string as well, which ensures that we end the loop.

---

## Related

- [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646525/6862601)